# Assign key shortcut to two actions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want a single key binding to perform 2+ actions. Is this possible?

I tried doing it the obvious way (by setting two shortcuts to use the same key binding), but it appears to only respect the most recently changed shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

The awesome [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros) plugin might be the best option.

As an example, let's say you want `cmd+\` to hide *both* the Activity Bar and the Sidebar.

Add the following to your user settings:

```
"macros": {
    "minimalMode": [
        "workbench.action.toggleActivityBarVisibility",
        "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility"
    ]
},
```

Add the following to your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "cmd+\\",
    "command": "macros.minimalMode"
},
```